# Configure iptables firewall to allow DHCP, DNS, HTTP, SMTP, FTP, IMAP, POP, and Squid ports – deny all other services.

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables, debian-squeeze

Configure iptables firewall to allow DHCP, DNS, HTTP, SMTP, FTP, IMAP, POP, and Squid ports – deny all other services.

1 pc for router ( place firewall)
1 pc for server ( place web,dhcp,ftp,etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use system-config-firewall if you have GUI installed on RHEL, Cent OS or Fedora systems. Then just put ticks and apply.